# Transaction not working

Tags: php, firebird, interbase

I have the following environment

**Wamp Version**    : 2.4
**Apache Version**  : 2.4.4
**PHP Version**     : 5.4.16

Firebird/InterBase Support             dynamic
Compile-time Client Library Version        Firebird API version 25
Run-time Client Library Version WI-V6.3.0.26074    Firebird 2.5

PDO
PDO drivers                                    firebird, mysql, sqlite

### PDO_Firebird

PDO Driver for Firebird/InterBase              enabled but the following php code is not working properly. The transaction is never rolled back.

```
<?php
    require_once 'KLogger.php';
    $log = new KLogger ( "log.txt" , KLogger::DEBUG );
    try
    {
        $db = new PDO("firebird:dbname=MY-SERVER:MBOOKS-DB", "sysdba", "masterkey");
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $result = $db->beginTransaction();
        $log->LogInfo('TRANSACTION ' . $result);
        $sql = "UPDATE control SET code = code + 1 WHERE ( company_id = 26 ) AND ( fin_year = '0000' ) AND ( item = 'SAL_ID' )";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        //$db->commit();
        $db->rollBack();
        $db = null;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $db->rollBack();
        $log->LogError($e->getMessage());
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException $e) 
    {
        $db->rollBack();
        $log->LogError($e->getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException $e) 
    {
        $db->rollBack();
        $log->LogError($e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check if  PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT is 0

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT,0);
```

Comment: Why the pdo_firebird don't detect this automatically and set the PDO attribute?